# How to take value from cin into vector.push_back() in one line?

Tags: c++

Can I do this in one line?

```
int temp;
cin >> temp;
vtr.push_back(temp);
```

For bonus points is there a way to also incorporate a for-loop alternative

```
 for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    int temp;
    cin >> temp;
    vtr.push_back(temp);
}
```

The caveat is I can't do something like `while(cin >> myInt)` since the read-in file has multiple lines but I only wanna read 5 at a time. I also have no idea how I could do a oneliner with cin like `vtr.push_back(cin >> ??? )`

Comment: Do you want to read the entire file into the vector? And why do you want to read 5 at a time?

Comment: Declare `temp` on the same decl as `i`, add `cin >> temp` to the conditional after the `i` check, and `vtr.push_back(temp)` before the increment. I have no idea whether that is what you want, but it is none-the-less doable.

Comment: I don't understand what is the reason not to do in multiple lines.

Comment: Is it allowed to write a separate library type somewhere?

Comment: And what do you want to happen if `cin >> temp` fails?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `std::istream_iterator<>`.  Here is an example which constructs a `std::vector` from the contents of stdin:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<int> vec{
        std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<int>()};
    for (int i : vec) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you would rather, you can use `push_back` in a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (std::istream_iterator<int> p{std::cin}, e; p != e; ++p) {
        vec.push_back(*p);
    }
    for (int i : vec) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMHO using `istream_iterator` to construct the vector is no better than using a `while(cin >>)` loop (which the OP does not want) since the "end" iterator will not be reached unless a read error occurs. In your second example, the first `for` loop can be replaced with a `std::copy()` statement: `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(vec));`

Comment: The second example is only there because the OP specifically asked for a loop version.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I do this in one line?

Not directly, but you can wrap it:

```
template<typename ContainerType>
void readValue(std::istream &in, ContainerType &container)
{
    ContainerType::value_type temp;
    if (in >> temp)
        container.push_back(temp);
}
```

Then it is a one-line call:

```
readValue(cin, vtr);
```

> For bonus points is there a way to also incorporate a for-loop alternative

If you use C++11 or later, you can use [`std::copy_n()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) with a [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 5, std::back_inserter(vtr));
```

Otherwise, just use a manual loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) readValue(cin, vtr);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the iterator solution shown in the other answer, you could add five elements to the end of the vector and then read new vales into them from the stream:

```
auto n = vtr.size();
vtr.resize(n + 5);
if (std::cin >> vtr[n] >> vtr[n+1] >> vtr[n+2] >> vtr[n+3] >> vtr[n+4])
{ }
else
{ /* report error */ }
```